Words similar to アンニュイ
The word アンニュイ seems like an exception to me, since it is able to act as an (na-)adjective while originating from a noun (loanword from French). I don't think there is any answer as to how it emerged, or how it came to be used that way, but are there any words that are similar to it?

Are you looking for list of na-adjectives written only in katakana, and therefore likely to be borrowings? I can easily find hundreds of them...

Another interpretation might be “loanwords that were originally nouns but were borrowed only as na-adjectives”.

Oh, so that's how you word it...
